# Rails 3 - Building a Form to Update a Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following two models:

```
class PhotoAlbum < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :project
    has_many :photos, :dependent => :destroy

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :photo_album
```

When the user is viewing a photo, the URL is like follows: "/photo_albums/40/photos?page=6"

On this photo view page (inside an album) I want to give the user the option to update the image, so I'm using the following:

```
<% form_for [:photo, @photos.first], :url => photo_album_photos_path, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>


<form method="post" id="edit_photo_124" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="edit_photo" action="/photo_albums/40/photos" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

Which I think is right? Problem is, when I click update, I get the following error:

```
No route matches "/photo_albums/40/photos"
```

Here are my routes, which look good, no?

```
photo_album_photo PUT    /photo_albums/:photo_album_id/photos/:id(.:format)       {:action=>"update", :controller=>"photos"}
photo PUT    /photos/:id(.:format)                                    {:action=>"update", :controller=>"photos"}
```

Thoughts? thanks

**UPDATE w config route file:**

```
resources :photos do
    resources :comments, :only => [:create, :update,:destroy], :constraint => {:context_type => "photos"}
    collection do
              post 'upload'
      get 'search'
    end
end


  resources :photo_albums do
        resources :comments, :only => [:create, :update,:destroy], :constraint => {:context_type => "photo_albums"}
      resources :photos
      collection do
          get 'search'
      end
    end
```

Comment: ok maybe I need this "<% form_for [:photo_album, @photos.first], :url => photo_album_photo_path, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>" tried that but it errors with "No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"photos"}" funny thing is I have a destory and I'm trying to update not destroy.

Comment: What does the <form> tag look like after you updated the :url arg?

Comment: if I use the URL tag above it errors with "No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"photos"}" if I make i PHOTOS_path, lowercase, it then looks like: <form method="post" id="edit_photo_124" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="edit_photo" action="/photo_albums/40/photos" accept-charset="UTF-8"> which then errors on submit with "No route matches "/photo_albums/40/photos"

Comment: Was that what you needed? just let me know

Comment: So wait, when you have the photo_path in your form tag you can't even see the view? It errors out while trying to render the view? And in the other scenario, it doesn't get the "no route" error until you submit the form? Curious.

Comment: Correct, "photo_album_photo_path" doesn't allow the page to render. but photo_album_photos_path does, but that doesn't seem to be posting to the right url, as it doesn't have the photo_id

Comment: There's nothing in my routes about photo it's all photos, that's normal right?

Comment: Here's the log with posting to PHOTOS "Started POST "/photo_albums/52/photos" for 127.0.0.1 at Mon Nov 01 14:11:56 -0700 2010" Maybe that's the problem, it's POSTING and not putting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your form to something like:

```
<% form_for [@photo_album, @photos.first], :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
```

where @photo_album is your photo_album object, or

```
<% form_for @photos.first, :url => photo_album_photo_path(@photo_album, @photo), :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
```

which is basically the same. To have this working, you should have the following in your route.rb:

```
resources :photo_albums do
  resources :photos
end
```

Comment: wow that worked. So I'm supposed to use @photo_album, not :photo_album, what's the difference? Why'd that make it work?

Comment: Also, paper_clip deletes the old photo that the update replaces. Is there a way to keep a version history of the photo? I'd like paperclip not to delete the previous photo. Ideas?